# ¿Como obtener el texto de un EditText directamente?

Tags: android-studio

Estoy realizando un ejercicio en el que debo de obtener el valor de un `EditText`.
Se que para ello debo de usar lo siguiente:

```
EditText edt = findViewById(R.id.id_edt);
String texto = edt.getText().toString();
```

Sin embargo, quisiera ahorrarme eso dado que no ocupare a `edt` más que para obtener su valor.

Lo que busco es algo como `String texto = findViewById(R.id.id_ext).getText().toString();` o similar, que me permita obtener el texto directamente, sin tener que declarar antes a `edt`.

¿Existe alguna forma de hacerlo?

**Edit**: `String texto = findViewById(R.id.id_ext).getText().toString();` no funciona. Cuando redacte la pregunta ya había probado esto y Android Studio marca en rojo `.getText()`, y no deja correrlo.

Comment: Lo que escribiste debería funcionar, cuál es el problema con eso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autor aquí.

Estuve viendo y parece que no hay forma directa de hacer lo que pregunto. Lo más cercano que encontré luego de experimentar es castear el `findViewById()` a un `EditText`. Solo así se vuelve posible usar los métodos `.getText().toString`.

Por lo tanto `String txtPrueba = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPrueba)).getText().toString();`

Answer (score 0):

La forma de realizarlo es precisamente como mencionas ya que debes obtener la referencia de la vista en el layout por medio de:

```
findViewById(R.id.id_ext)
```

Así que está sería la forma adecuada

```
String texto = findViewById(R.id.id_ext).getText().toString();
```